# Is Borel measurable function composed with Lebesgue measurable function a Lebesgue measurable function?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $g$ be a Borel measurable function and $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function.

Then, is $g(f(x))$ a Lebesgue measurable function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because Borel/Lebesgue measurability means that $f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel/Lebesgue measurable for every **Borel** set $A$.

Hence,

$$
(g \circ f)^{-1}(A) = f^{-1} ( g^{-1}(A))
$$

is Lebesgue-measurable, because $g^{-1}(A)$ is Borel-measurable.

But composition the other way around is in general **not** measurable.